Android 13 Service on Samsung won't ignore battery optimizations
The app was added in configuration:
Battery and device care -> Battery -> Limits for background usage
-> Apps never in automatic rest
The app has a foreground service which calls startForeground(...) and
then
    String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName);


powerManager.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations always returns false. Is there any work around?
Aquiring a WakeLock doesn't help.
The device is a Samsung Galaxy S20 with Android 13.
From the manifest:
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />

